# I'm Having an error with calling a constructor with another constructor

Tags: java, constructor

Using the below code which is the closest to any solution I keep getting an error saying "(" or "[" expected and under that ";" expected. I'm not sure what I am missing.

```
public class Manager extends SalariedSubordinate implements IManager{

private ArrayList<ISubordinate> listOfSubordinates;
private double managerBonusFund = 5000;
private double baseSalary;

public Manager(double baseSalary, IManager manager, ArrayList<ISubordinate> subordinates) {
    this.baseSalary = baseSalary;
    this.manager = manager;
    this.listOfSubordinates = subordinates;
```

}

```
public Manager(double baseSalary, IManager manager){       
   this(baseSalary, manager, new ArrayList<ISubordinate> subordinates);
}
```

Comment: `new ArrayList<ISubordinate> subordinates` isn´t how you initialize a new `List`, mabye try it with `new ArrayList<ISubordinate>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new empty array list, you would normally do this:

```
new ArrayList<SomeType>();
```

Right?

Then why did you write

```
new ArrayList<ISubordinate> subordinates
```

when you pass a new array list to the constructor? Where are the `()`s? Why do you add the word `subordinate`?

So just add the `()` and delete the word `subordinate`:

```
this(baseSalary, manager, new ArrayList<ISubordinate>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second constructor should be like below.

```java
public Manager(double baseSalary, IManager manager){       
   this(baseSalary, manager, new ArrayList<ISubordinate>());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer has already been posted in here ();... You should look at the proper way to create an ArrayList and better understand it with more depth .   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm